# MS Teams: default country code when dialing

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have an NZ number, but I'm currently in Sydney. Whenever I enter a local number (in Sydney), e.g. click a link, it adds +64 (NZ) by default. How do I change it to +61 (Aus)?

Comment: If you add the country code yourself what happens?

Comment: If I click, e.g., a tel link, it asks me for approval. Then, I copy the number, cancel, paste the number, change to 61, and dial. I was looking for a quicker, smoother operation.

Comment: Can you use a VPN located in NZ to trick the geolocation capabilities of MS Teams?

Comment: I'm located in Sydney. I think it determines the default extension from my NZ phone number.